# Strange Mouse movement issue

Tags: mouse

I've just installed Loki and I'm getting very strange mouse movement behavior. Touchpad works fine, but if I want to use my Logitech M310 mouse.. well it's not usable.

I can move the mouse pointer to the top or bottom of the screen, but moving left or right makes it go really slow.

Please help!

EDIT: If I plug the mouse into another computer it works OK.

Answer (score 1):

So the hidpoint suggestion sent me on an oddessy of trying to install 32bit libraries to run it's xWindows install. BLEH.

I installed Solaar instead and the problem with my mouse buttons was resolved. I get the added benefit of seeing information about the unifying receiver in a graphic interface.

From your terminal

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install solaar

I hope this provides you a better working solution.

Comment: I've had a similar issue after a regular pkg upgrade today, but even the touchpad didn't work fine, rejumping always to the same location on screen. Luckily `solar` solved the problem (I had to install it in recovery mode [allow network then choose root cmd line]).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be a good fix for you but many people using Logitech devices have had a great deal of luck using the HIDPoint drivers to get devices working. Here is a link to their page:

https://www.hidpoint.com/hidpoint

Again, I'm not sure if this will help with your particular device or issue but it may be a good starting point.

Good Luck!!!